# I have a problem when the awesome rotate font icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

i have a problem when rotate a fontawesome icon. if I rotate it 180 degrees the icon moves a little. looks at the screenshot.

[Not Rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwZkP.jpg)

[Rotate 180Deg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH2Fs.jpg)

Code:

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-down icon-show"></i>
.icon-show {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}
.icon-show:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: btw I don't see any change : http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/49bkrvht/3/

Comment: Tried it in fiddle and it works fine. Could you post more code? Likely an issue with its parent container.

Comment: u can see the different if i rotate 180 the arrow is moved a little to the right

Comment: @ZTzTopia I just added fiddle, if you see there you don't see the change, and yes I can see the difference in image. We may need some more code to find what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.icon-show {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}
.icon-show:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x icon-show"></i>
```